# Unexpected C# warning: instance member hides static method on base class

Tags: c#

I'm curious if I've run into a compiler bug in C#. (I'm using Visual Studio 2013 Update 2. No Roslyn yet.)

The following code produces an unexpected warning. The Year field (or property) should not, I think, hide the static Year method on the base class, because the two are called very differently - one on an instance variable and one on a class. I don't see how the two could ever conflict in a name resolution.

What am I missing?

**UPDATE:** I understand that the field and static method have the same name. However, the way that those two things are invoked is *completely different* and I don't see how there could ever be any confusion. In other words, from the point of view of the type system, it seems wrong to say that the public field "hides" the base class's public *static* method. Can anyone provide a scenario where there would actually be a conflict?

```cs
public class Timeframe
{
    public readonly DateTime From;
    public readonly DateTime To;

    public Timeframe(DateTime from, DateTime to)
    {
        From = from;
        To = to;
    }

    public static YearTimeframe Year(int year)
    {
        return new YearTimeframe(year);
    }

    // .. similar factory methods, e.g. Month and Day, omitted
}

public class YearTimeframe : Timeframe
{
    // WARNING: 'YearTimeframe.Year' hides inherited member 'Timeframe.Year(int)'.
    // (a public property w/ private readonly backing field has same problem)
    public readonly int Year;

    public YearTimeframe(int year)
        : base(
        new DateTime(year, 1, 1),
        new DateTime(year, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59))
    {
        this.Year = year;
    }
}

// .. similar classes, e.g. MonthTimeframe and DayTimeframe, omitted
```

Comment: Seems correct to me - you have a property called `Year` and a method called `Year`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is clearly defined as a warning in section 3.7.1.2 of the specification:

> A constant, field, property, event, or type introduced in a class or struct hides all base class members with the same name.
>   ...
>   Contrary to hiding a name from an outer scope, hiding an accessible name from an inherited scope causes a warning to be reported.

The "way they are invoked" is not terribly important because you could have something like

```
public class YearTimeframe : Timeframe
{
    // WARNING: 'YearTimeframe.Year' hides inherited member 'Timeframe.Year(int)'.
    // (a public property w/ private readonly backing field has same problem)
    public readonly int Year;

    public YearTimeframe(int year)
        : base(
        new DateTime(year, 1, 1),
        new DateTime(year, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59))
    {
        this.Year = year;
        Method(Year);
    }

    private static void Method(int y)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("int");
    }

    private static void Method(Func<int, YearTimeframe> f)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Func");
    }
}
```

Now which version of Method is invoked? Either one is potentially valid. The answer is that the simple name Year resolves to the field in this case because it hides the static method from the base class.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I had been missing - the fact that **from within a class** you can call static methods on that class and its base classes **without prefixing with the class name.** That's the one situation where there would be a conflict in name resolution.

Comment: And here I was thinking it was to prevent people who switch from Java to C# from shooting themselves in the foot (Java is perfectly happy to execute `static` methods from an instance, although modern compilers issue a warning).

Answer (score 2):

The warning is pretty clear, since you have a method named `Year` in base class and a field named `Year` in child class. Now why this warning appears, as one is a method and other is a field, The answer is in the documentation.

[new Modifier (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/435f1dw2.aspx)

> Generally, a constant, field, property, or type that is introduced in
>   a class or struct hides all base **class members that share its
>   name**.

AND

> A method introduced in a class or struct hides properties, fields, and
>   types that share that name in the base class. It also hides all base
>   class methods that have the same signature.

Some more explanation:

Your warning has nothing to do with `static` being involved. Even if your method in base class is an instance method, you will still get the warning. But the main reason is **same Name.** When you introduced a new field `Year` in your child class, it hides all the **members of base class with same name**.

You can get rid of the warning using `new` modifier within your child class, but usually this warning reflects issue with your code structure. It would be better to rename your method to `GetYear`, instead of `Year` in your base class. IMO.

Comment: I'm afraid that doesn't help. I've edited my question to be clearer. Why is it that the compiler thinks the child class's property hides a static method on the base class? The documentation you cited does not directly address that situation.

Comment: @LarsKemmann, it doesn't have anything to do with `static`. Even if your method is an instance method, you will still get the warning. But the main reason is same, `Name`. When you introduced a new field `Year` in your child class, it hides all the members of base class with **same name**

Comment: But there's no possible way that the two can be confused, @Habib. I intentionally made it static because the way the two are accessed is totally distinct, and **the compiler knows that** (at least according to IntelliSense!).

Comment: @LarsKemmann, Are you questioning why C# compiler behaves in this manner ?

Comment: Yes, that was my question. See Mike's answer - he shows the situation where the compiler is unable to resolve the difference, which makes it necessary to provide the `new` workaround.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, they are both called "Year", but one is a static function and the other a property.  You would need to use the "new" keyword added for the compiler to be happy.

```
public new readonly int Year;
```

Comment: yes, that fixes the compiler warning, but I'm asking why the warning is generated in the first place. :)

Comment: Basically, you can't override a static method, period. Here's a post that describes this in more detail:  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kirillosenkov/archive/2008/02/06/how-to-override-static-methods.aspx.  

From the article: "Overriding usual (instance) members uses the virtual dispatch mechanism to separate the contract from the implementation. The contract is known at compile time (instance member signature), but the implementation is only known at runtime (concrete type of object provides a concrete implementation). You don't know the concrete type of the implementation at compile time."

Comment: I'm not overriding it though! I'm adding a class member in a completely different context, and the two should never be able to conflict. In fact, the blog post you link to supports my confusion: "With static members, you call them by explicitly specifying the type on which they are defined. Which means, you directly call the implementation, which, again, is not bound to any contract."

Comment: The fact that you have a conflict like this is also an indication that the code members should be renamed, IMHO.  Year is a property name, a concrete thing, where a factory method should named to indicate something is being created, like "CreateYearTimeFrame".  Also, the base class shouldn't know anything about the derived classes, so your factory method for a YearTimeframe object should be in the YearTimeframe class.

Comment: Fair point. It may not be the best example. I did end up renaming the factory methods to `FromYear`, etc.. I also didn't show the fact that the base constructor will be `protected internal` and the child classes marked `sealed`, so that I have a simple and efficient overload+factory system fully contained within a single assembly. The `FromYear(int)` method is then just more convenient on the base class. I agree it's not strictly necessary though. :)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot call the static function `Year` from the inside of `YearTimeframe`, you have to prefix it with the class.

so

```
public class YearTimeframe : Timeframe
{
    // WARNING: 'YearTimeframe.Year' hides inherited member 'Timeframe.Year(int)'.
    // (a public property w/ private readonly backing field has same problem)
    public readonly int Year;

    public YearTimeframe(int year)
        : base(
            new DateTime(year, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(year, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59))
        {
            this.Year = year;

            Year();
        }
    }
}
```

will give you an compiler error.

you have to call it with

```
public class YearTimeframe : Timeframe
{
    // WARNING: 'YearTimeframe.Year' hides inherited member 'Timeframe.Year(int)'.
    // (a public property w/ private readonly backing field has same problem)
    public readonly int Year;

    public YearTimeframe(int year)
        : base(
            new DateTime(year, 1, 1),
            new DateTime(year, 12, 31, 23, 59, 59))
        {
            this.Year = year;

            Timeframe.Year();
        }
    }
}
```

hence the warning.
and also

`YearTimeframe.Year()` from the outside will not work.
the `new` keyword will get rid of the warning, and ensures that you (as the developer) know what you are doing here.